# Cylon Eye Whoosh?

Tags: scifi, whoosh

I've really been racking my brain about this, and it seems like it should be so simple, but I find that I have no idea how to make a sound that sounds like the Cylon eye whoosh.  Any ideas?  The sound came from the 70s, so the sound synthesis should  be relatively simple.

Comment: You want to dig out a link, so we don't have to watch entire episodes in the off chance of hearing one? Also, was the sound the same in the 2004 show?

Comment: It's on this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6-eWRLlGO5Y

The second half.  I'm thinking maybe a triangle wave, low pass or band pass filtered, two different notes.  And then maybe ring modulation?  Reverb?  Not sure.